# Interact with executable invoked from batch file

Tags: asp.net, shell, batch-file, ftp, cmd

I have an executable file that opens a command prompt and connects to an FTP.  We use this to download and upload files by manually typing the `get` and `put` commands into the command window.  My ultimate goal is to automate the FTP process by using either an `ASP.NET` console app or a batch file, either one will work.  I've tried calling the executable in a batch file followed by the ftp commands but it waits for the executable to exit before it runs the next command in the batch file.

`"C:\MyFtp.exe"
get ‘FtpFile.txt’ C:\temp\MyFile.txt
timeout /t 5`

Just to illustrate, if I open the batch file above, I want it to execute the `get` command inside of the `MyFtp.exe` executable.  But instead it waits for me to type `quit` before executing the other commands.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: It depends on your FTP program whether it supports reading input from somewhere else. Try `MyFtp.exe < commands.txt` where commands.txt contains the FTP commands. Can you tell us the name of the program? If not, can you have a look at `MyFtp.exe /?` or `MyFTP.exe -help` and post the result?

Comment: `MyFTP.exe -help` comes back with an error.  When I open it correctly, the command prompt shows `CDFTP:` and I can type `help` there and it displays all the common ftp commands.  `MyFTP.exe` is a custom executable that we inherited from another company and we weren't given any documentation on it.

Comment: How about `MyFTP.exe < commands.txt`? Is there a good reason why you cannot use any other FTP program?

Comment: `MyFTP.exe < commands.txt` actually does work.  I initially was using the `Process` class in `VB.NET` and specifying the `StandardInput` so that I could type commands that way (similar to Rich's answer below), but this is cleaner.  Thanks! @ThomasW.

Answer (score 3):

This is a vbscript which does what you are requesting. You can activate it via batch file "C:\windows\system32\cscript.exe C:\my\file\location.vbs" or directly if you are on a 32 bit system. View vbscript info section for more details.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("""C:\my folder loc\MyFtp.exe""")'Keep double quotes for specific path names

Do Until Success = True
    Success = objShell.AppActivate("Untitle - FTP") ' Put application title text here (e.g. Untitle - Notepad)
    Wscript.Sleep 1000
Loop
enter code here
objShell.SendKeys "get 'FtpFile.Txt' C:\temp\MyFile.txt"
objShell.SendKeys "~" 'enter
objShell.SendKeys "timeout /t 5"
objShell.SendKeys "~" 'enter
```

Comment: This should work, as I was using the `Process` class in `VB.NET` and specifying the `StandardInput` so I could type commands that way, which this is using the same idea.